# method match1.regex seems not working in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm following a tutorial on regular expressions in ruby, but a method called regex that seems not working

```
Tutorial

re = /(\w*)\s(\w*),\s?([\w\s]*)/
match1 = str1.match re
match2 = str2.match re
match1.regex # => wsw,s[ws]     (this is IRB's unique way of showing regular expressions; it will still work normally)

My console

The regex method the method throws an error

1.9.3-p547 :033 > re = /(\w*)\s(\w*),\s?([\w\s]*)/
 => /(\w*)\s(\w*),\s?([\w\s]*)/ 
1.9.3-p547 :034 >     match1 = str1.match re
 => #<MatchData "Joe Schmo, Plumber" 1:"Joe" 2:"Schmo" 3:"Plumber"> 
1.9.3-p547 :035 >     match2 = str2.match re
 => #<MatchData "Stephen Harper, Prime Minister" 1:"Stephen" 2:"Harper" 3:"Prime Minister"> 
1.9.3-p547 :036 > match1.regex
NoMethodError: undefined method `regex' for #<MatchData "Joe Schmo, Plumber" 1:"Joe" 2:"Schmo" 3:"Plumber">
    from (irb):36
    from /home/fernando/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p547 :037 >
```

Comment: Let's go through the steps to solve your problem. The error message says that the class `match1.class => MatchData` does not have an instance method `regex`.  The *[docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/MatchData.html)* for that class list instance methods (`#==`, 
`#[]`, `#begin`, `#captures`, and so on).  There is no method `regex`, but there is a method `regexp`, so it seems you misspelled the method name. Aside: it would have been helpful to have  included `str1` and `str2` in your answer, so readers could reproduce your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be

```
match1.regexp
```

with a final 'p'

Comment: match1.regexp
 => /(\w*)\s(\w*),\s?([\w\s]*)/

Comment: the response is similar

Comment: this is a link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-regular-expressions--net-19812